What exactly is this comma doing?

To be uneasy because to the lawyer it was no more than a technical problem, wasn't justified.

EDIT: I'm also asking why it sounds "off" (as a native speaker) and whether it's covered by any valid uses of a comma in a grammar book.
When I occasionally use a comma this way, I feel like I'm making a slight grammatical mistake for the sake of clarity or style. Not sure if that intuition is correct.


The sentence is awkward, but the comma does separate "problem" and "wasn't justified" to avoid saying the probem wasn't justified. I'd add an earlier comma after uneasy to balance the aside.

Yosef -- that would be my first instinct too. But then I'd feel like I was separating the explanatory clause from "uneasy," and saying "to be uneasy wasn't justified, because to the lawyer it was no more than a technical problem."

That is what the sentence is saying, that is was not justified to be uneasy.

This question is similar to: Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Actually, commas between the subject and the verb and predicate – a mistake or acceptable? is closer, but claimed to be a duplicate.

BillJ writes there: 'In Present-day English there is normally a strong prohibition on punctuation separating subject and verb. Your examples certainly violate that prohibition and thus would normally be wrong. Why they were written that way? Who knows?  // Sometimes, an enormous subject is set off by a comma in spite of this, in the interests of clarity, but the correct solution is to rephrase.

Thanks Edwin — I’d say my example is slightly different, but close enough that I’m satisfied with your/Bill’s answer and will accept the duplicate tag

(Yosef — I think not quite, because the original sentence says that it was not justified to be uneasy for this reason; there may have been another good reason.)

Voted to reopen because the sentence the OP cites is more complex than the sentence in the question cited as duplicate.

The logic of the sentence is also questionable. I would have liked to see a few sentences above as well for corroboration, but it appears that the character narrating is the one who feels "uneasy" -- not  "at ease".  This would have made sense: "To be put at ease because the lawyer considered it no more than a technical problem was unjustified".  That is, "no more than" inidicates that something is less troubling than it is believed to be. But the sentence says the opposite: "To be uneasy because the lawyer considered it no more than a technical problem was not justified".  continued...

That sentence would question the lawyer's motives, and suggest the lawyer was not to be trusted.  And so one wonders if "because" should have been stricken from the sentence and that clause separated with em-dashes:  "To be uneasy —the lawyer, after all, considered it no more than a technical problem— was unjustified."  If "to be uneasy was unjustified" then the lawyer's word should be trusted.

Tim -- You're right that the protagonist is the client, with close third person narration. But it's a Hitchcock-style wrong-man plot, in which he's being framed for a murder he didn't commit. So the reason he feels uneasy is that the lawyer might not really believe he's innocent, i.e. his story sounds less plausible than he had hoped.

@TimR The main problem is closure with the wrong duplicate. A more relevant duplicate, addressing a similar sentence structure to this post's, is given in Edwin's comment. So do we re-open this question and then VTC as duplicate of the other question? I think that's probably a better option than leaving it as it is, pointing to an irrelevant question.

I fail to see how John Purdy's answer 'It was standard for much of Modern English history to use a comma to separate a complex subject ... from the rest of the sentence. This is in line with the purpose of punctuation in general—to indicate prosody. Many speakers actually do pause at that point in a sentence, so a comma seems only natural.
In the passages below, [,] denotes a comma which is present in the original text, but is widely (albeit arbitrarily) considered incorrect in contemporary English. ...

Treason against the United States[,] shall consist only in levying War against them, or in adhering to their Enemies, giving them Aid and Comfort. //
A well regulated Militia[,] being necessary to the security of a free State, the right of the people to keep and bear Arms[,] shall not be infringed. //
In short: it’s best avoided unless you’re intentionally writing in the style of the early 1800s.' [Note that the comma after 'Militia' actually disallows the absolute phrase that must certainly be intended.] ... doesn't address this comprehensively. Duplicate.

The pared-down structure of the sentence is:
"To be uneasy wasn't justified."
The next level of complexity is to add an explanatory clause after uneasy:
To be uneasy, because it was no more than a technical problem, wasn't justified.
and the last level is:
To be uneasy, because to the lawyer it was no more than a technical problem, wasn't justified.
I have not enclosed "to the lawyer" in commas because it makes the sentence over-punctuated and merely confuses.
From this viewpoint, the comma you mention is the second of the two commas required to separate the explanatory clause from the main thrust of the sentence. The first comma is missing, and this obscures the function of the second one.

There have been other discussions on the insertion of a comma between an overweight subject and verb; I seem to remember examples where the 'relict parenthetical offset' single comma wouldn't work. Sometimes, it seems to be a deliberate 'lesser of two evils' strategy.

Anton, isn't your second sentence ambiguous? The added clause could be explaining the unease, or explaining why it wasn't justified. I suspect this is what the author was trying to avoid by leaving out that first comma.

The comma is doing (the second half (with nothing doing the first half) of) the job of indicating that the subject of the verb phrase wasn't justified is To be uneasy. The sentence could be paraphrased as "Even though the lawyer experienced it as merely a technical problem, being uneasy wasn't justified."

That really doesn’t mean the same thing. It’s not even though, it’s because.

@Xanne, the structure of the sentence is essentially To be uneasy because of X wasn't justified. So what the sentence means is that X was no reason be be uneasy. In other words, "Although X, being uneasy wasn't justified."
